# Взаимодействие с клавиатурой на Си/Си++

Tags: c++, c, клавиатура

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ через язык программирования Си/Си++ заставить компьютер думать, что мы нажали какую-то клавишу на клавиатуре, при этом не нажимая ее? То есть написать такой код, который будет отправлять сигналы якобы нажатых клавиш компьютеру, при этом клавиатуру мы не будем задействовать. Если есть, то подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть, что читать, буду благодарен.

Comment: "Заставить его думать" для *вашей* программы (консольной?), или для какой-то другой?

Comment: а как написать программу не нажав на клавиш?

Comment: Есть несколько технологий. 1)Перенаправление ввода-вывода (консоль, не требует указания ОС как правило) 2)Емуляция soft-нажатия на клавишу. 3) Емуляция нажатия на уровне драйвера. 4)Использование "клавиатур" на чипе (USB).

Comment: @Harry для другой

Comment: Для \*nix-ов смотрите на *псевдотерминалы* (pty)

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void ClickKey(int vKeyCode)
{
    keybd_event(vKeyCode, 0, 0, 0); // зажать клавишу
    keybd_event(vKeyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // отпустить клавишу
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        ClickKey('A'); // нажать и отпустить клавишу A
        Sleep(1000); // подождать 1 секунду (1000мс)
    }
}
```